# Random Swap between two List Object

Tags: c#

Im trying to do a random swap between two of my list objects.

Heres what I got so far:

```
public class Inventory
{
    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Inventory()
    {
        items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item("Ipod"),
            new Item("Samsung"),
            new Item("Motorolla"),
            new Item("Huawei")
        };
    }
}
```

Under `Form_load`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Both objects are initiated with the default values from Inventory.cs
    var myInv = new Inventory();
    lstBox.Items.Add(myInv);

    var myInv2 = new Inventory();
    lstBox.Items.Add(myInv);
}
```

So once I initiated a random swap, a random object from `myInv1` will be swapped towards `myInv2` and then one object from `myInv2` will just fill in that spot in `myInv1`.

At the moment, this is the best I can describe my challenge but
I'll be happy to comment as soon as I can if anything seems muddy.

Thank you

Comment: why you have `items` and `Items` ? they seem redundant and disconnected. You only need `public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();`

Comment: In the `Load` method, you are not attempting to swap, you are creating new items, which is not the idea.

Comment: @Jaime Yep thats intentional, cause I got a listbox to display the list then I need to create a method that does the above then further display the List objects again in the listbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Random class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx).

I cleared out portions of your code not completely related to the original question "how do I swap two items randomly in two lists?" After that, using `Random`, we randomly select an item in each list and swap them.

```
public void DoRandomSwap()
{
    var myInv1 = new Inventory();
    var myInv2 = new Inventory();

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int myInv1Random = rnd.Next(myInv1.Items.Count);
    int myInv2Random = rnd.Next(myInv2.Items.Count);

    Item tempItem1 = myInv1.Items[myInv1Random];
    Item tempItem2 = myInv2.Items[myInv2Random];

    myInv1.Items[myInv1Random] = tempItem2;
    myInv2.Items[myInv2Random] = tempItem1;
}
```

Also, I cleaned up your `Inventory` class since you didn't appear to initialize your lists correctly:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Inventory()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item("Ipod"),
            new Item("Samsung"),
            new Item("Motorolla"),
            new Item("Huawei")
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, you didn't include your code for `Item` so I included a simple version as per how you seem to be using it:

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public Item(string itemName)
    {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!